# Tracking second object to a pose

Tags: pose-mode

I have a human mesh with armature I have imported from Makehuman.  I want to put an arrow through the human to illustrate a bullet path.  I then want to pose the human mesh to illustrate how the bullet path would change as the orientation of the body changes (e.g. standing straight versus bent over), e.g.:

[image]

versus

[image]

I did the above by posing the human and then manually repositioning the arrow, but I'd prefer to just pose the human mesh and have the arrow follow.

The human consists of three meshes, one for the head and arms, one for the shirt and pants, and one for the feet and shoes.

I have tried:

1. Making the arrow a "child of" the shirt and pants mesh.  This works for moving the human mesh as a whole, but does not affect anything when I change pose.
2. Doing a boolean union with the mesh of the shirt and pants.  This causes a couple of vertices from the shirt to stick with the arrow when the body is reposed, but does not move the arrow.  I have tried doing the boolean both before and after the armature constraint application.

Any pointers to tutorials or information on how to do this would be appreciated.

Thanks!

billo

Answer (score 1):

OK, for anybody interested, I figured out what I was doing wrong.  Clearly a newbie mistake.

My mistake was to try to make the arrow mesh the child of the body mesh.  Instead, I needed to make the arrow mesh the child of an individual bone in the armature. The trick was to choose the right bone, since in my case the spine had a few of them. Nonetheless, once I chose the right bone, it worked great.

The other thing that misled me a little was that my human is an export from Makehuman, and the naming of the parts was a little confusing.  When I first tried to add constraints I couldn't find the armature to try it, but on review, it was there.  In my case Export: was the mesh, and "Export" itself was the armatureds and the human in general.

So, here you see me making the arrow a child of the left clavicle of the "Exports" armature (and also note that *everything* seems to be labeled "Exports").  Also note that I did not include Scale in the parenting.

[image]

Now I go into pose mode with the human, and move any of the bones, and the arrow follows the clavicle like it should:
[image]

So, it turns out that it was easy (once I spent a few hours working on it...)